# Why does .gitignore file not work in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to ignore .idea/ folder and all the files inside it.

Above is my .gitignore file and I changed only this part:

```
### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea/
*.xml
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
```

But when I `git add .` and then commit it does not work. It works when I write `git rm -r --cached .idea`. Why?

```
target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**/target/
!**/src/test/**/target/

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea/
*.xml
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
### Eclipse ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
/.nb-gradle/
build/
!**/src/main/**/build/
!**/src/test/**/build/

### VS Code ###
.vscode/

### Mac OS ###
.DS_Store
```

Comment: In your full .gitignore file that you posted there is a back-tick at the start of your _IntelliJ IDEA_ comment ... `\`### IntelliJ IDEA ###` — is that really there in the file? or is it a paste error?

Comment: @StephenP No, there is not, actually. When I wrote it here, it required from me to format the lines of code. So, it is the result of formatting.

Comment: What do you mean with "when I `git add`, it does not work"? _What_ does not _work_?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a bit like you might have already added your `.idea` file to the repo in a previous commit.

The `.gitignore` config won't remove files that have already been committed before you added them to `.gitignore`. This is why you need to manually remove `.idea` from your repo (and commit that change). Once you've done that, `.idea` will no longer show up as modified/etc., nor will it end up in commits going forward.